# Inheritance, need advices

Tags: c#, inheritance

Let's say I have an ai or player, I want him to be able to use different weapons.
My design with weapons:

```
public class Weapon()
{
    public virtual void FireWeapon(){} // this is useless for melee weapons
    public virtual void SwingMelee(){} // this is useless for guns
    public virtual void Reload(){} // this is also useless for melee weapons
}
```

Then in the ai controller class I simply call the function I want him to do.
This is where the ugly part is (I think)...
Controller class have a list containing some different weapons of ai and a weapon which is being used.

```
public class WeaponController
{
   private List<Weapon> someWeapons;
   private Weapon aWeapon;
   public void Main()
   {
      if(/*"Some action or a button click" &&*/ aWeapon.CanSwingMelee() )
         aWeapon.SwingMelee(); 
      if(/*"Some action or a button click" &&*/ aWeapon.CanReload() )
         aWeapon.Reload();
   }
}
```

What is the better way to implement this? do you have any advices?
Seems that for every different action in a new weapon, I need to implement a function in the most parent Weapon class and I don't think it's a good idea...

Comment: Why not just make the virtual method `Use`, and whether it's a swing or a shot, it's just used... why be so specific? It's going to do damage at the end of the day, right, that should be what counts

Comment: I'd create an interface with a `UseWeapon` method and then implement classes that fire or swing based on what they are.  Basically you want the weapon to know how it's used.

Comment: the functions are just for explaining my problem with this design. for example Reloading weapon is also useless for melee weapons...

Comment: use interface, John Wu's answer is perfect imho.

Comment: You'd better contact a lawyer to help you draft and notarize a will--oh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capability of an in-game object can be represented by an interface; you can check if a capability is present by attempting to cast to the interface.  What's more, these interfaces can overlap, e.g. both melee and ranged weapons might both have an `Attack` method.

So for example:

```
public interface IWeapon
{
    void Attack();
}

public interface IRangedWeapon
{
    bool IsInRange(ITargetable target);
}

public interface IRequiresAmmunition
{
    void Reload();
    int  AmmoRemaining { get; set; }
}

public class Sword : IWeapon
{
    public virtual void Attack() { //code }
}

public class Rifle : IWeapon, IRequiresAmmunition, IRangedWeapon
{
    public virtual void Attack() { //code }
    public virtual void Reload() { //code }
    public virtual int  AmmoRemaining { get { } set { } }
    public virtual bool IsInrange (ITargetable target) { //code }
}

public class LaserGun: IWeapon, IRangedWeapon
{
    public virtual void Attack() { //code }
    public virtual bool IsInrange (ITargetable target) { //code }
}


public class WeaponController
{
   private List<IWeapon> someWeapons;
   private IWeapon aWeapon;
   private ITargetable currentTarget;

   public void Weapon_OnUse()
   {
       if (!currentTarget.IsHostile) return;

       if (this.IsInMeleeRange(currentTarget))
       {
           aWeapon.Attack();
           return;
       }
       var w = aWeapon as IRangedWeapon;

       if (w != null && w.IsInRange(currentTarget)
       {
           aWeapon.Attack();
           return;
       }

       context.HUD.Warn("Out of range");

   }

   public void Weapon_OnReload()
   {
       var w = aWeapon as IRequiresAmmunition;
       if (w != null) 
       {
            w.Reload();
            context.HUD.DisplayAmmo(w.AmmoRemaining);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this looks much better :) also nice interface example

Comment: I can see that `Weapon_OnUse` method getting long and out of control. It would be difficult to test.

Comment: Yep... this happens on Stackoverflow a lot... there is a limit to how much I will refactor a poster's sample code when all I'm doing is demonstrating a principle in action. Could make for an interesting (other) question though.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like what `abstract` classes and inheritance is for:

```
public abstract class Weapon {
    public abstract void Attack();
    public abstract void Reload();
}

public class MeleeWeapon : Weapon {
    public override void Attack() {
        // swing sword
    }
    public override void Reload() {
        // ignore reload
    }
}
public class GunWeapon : Weapon {
    public override void Attack() {
        // fire gun
    }
    public override void Reload() {
        // load weapon from inventory
    }
}

public class WeaponController {
    private List<Weapon> someWeapons;
    private Weapon aWeapon;
    public void Main() {
        if (/*"Some action or a button click" */)
            aWeapon.Attack();
        else if (/* some other button click */)
            aWeapon.Reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but the only issue is not the Attack. it is all kinds of different behaviours according to some other actions like a button click

Comment: @31thUser your examples only give attack and reload, give a concrete example not covered by this answer

Comment: That's why I put `Reload` in the root `Weapon` class?

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. So you're saying that this is not that ugly at all? okayy.. thanks

Comment: @31thUser if you have actions specific to one weapon (or subclass) (Polish perhaps) then add it to that specifc class or subclass.

Comment: @pm100 then I will need to type check and downcast. I just dont want to do that...

Comment: What if you have a spear that you can both throw or strike with? What if you have a gun that you can swing like a club if it's empty? The OP defines several different ways to attack, but this solution specifies that each weapon can only do one of those things.

Comment: Also, why should a sword have a `Reload` method. What if you come up with a new weapon that does something other than `Attack` and `Reload`? This approach will require you to add it to the base class and then modify every single derived class to override it, most with empty overrides. You'll have to change classes that have no reason to change. That's a violation of the open/closed principle.

Comment: In that case, implement the empty method in the base class? Also, I'm not sure I agree - a change in the abstract base class is a change to all the classes. They do have a reason to change, unless you somehow know a priori how those classes will handle the new action.

Comment: @NetMage That's exactly the problem. If I create some new weapon with an action that applies to just that weapon, putting it in an abstract class requires me to change every other class for reasons irrelevant to those classes. I have to give them all methods they don't need, like `Sword.Reload()`. Then if I decide to add another attack to `Sword`, I have to add it to everything else. `Gun.Slice()` and `GrenadeLauncher.Slice()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend an approach that requires you to create new interfaces for every new behavior and check the type of the weapon. What about something like this:

(This is a *very* rough draft.)

```
public abstract class Weapon
{
    protected Weapon(WeaponCommandStrategy[] commandStrategies)
    {
        CommandStrategies = commandStrategies;
    }

    protected IEnumerable<WeaponCommandStrategy> CommandStrategies { get; }

    public void Use(WeaponCommand command)
    {
        var strategy = CommandStrategies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Command == command);
        strategy?.Execute();
    }
}

public enum WeaponCommand
{
    Fire,
    Swing,
    Reload
}

public abstract class WeaponCommandStrategy
{
    public WeaponCommand Command { get; private set; }

    protected WeaponCommandStrategy(WeaponCommand command)
    {
        Command = command;
    }

    public abstract void Execute();
}
```

Now you can give a weapon whatever behaviors you want it to have in the form of various instances of `WeaponCommandStrategy`. If a command is sent to a weapon, it executes it. If it doesn't support a command it ignores it. You could add a property to a weapon exposing the available commands so that you could display a list of available commands.

```
public class Sword : Weapon
{
    // Perhaps use dependency injection here
    public Sword() 
        : base(new WeaponCommandStrategy[] { new SwordSwingStrategy() })
    {
    }
}

public class SwordSwingStrategy : WeaponCommandStrategy
{
    public SwordSwingStrategy() : base(WeaponCommand.Swing) { }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        // Do whatever it does
    }
}
```

This essentially makes a `Weapon` a composition of various things that a weapon can do. If several weapons behave similarly they can share strategies vs. having code duplicated between various weapons.

Comment: Yes it can work. I'll upvote, however when I compare the john wu's answer, all we get would be deleting some downcast code for every command which is quite good, only disadvantage I think is passing all the needed data to WeaponCommandStrategy to execute a command. Still not sure which one to use :)

Comment: After I think a while Your suggestion is way better. And To get rid of useless command searchs, weapon can also tell controller which commands it can use .

Comment: Depending on how complex your system is gonna be a I would personally do a mix of both methods (interface and this one). Interface used to define what weapon can and cannot do, and strategy for specifics on how they do things.

Comment: In most cases I would rather not inspect an object to see what its type is. It violates the open/closed principle on the class that's doing the inspection. Every time we create a new behavior we'll need to create a new interface and then check for that interface. Better to know what the type is and tell it what to do. Then that type decides how to handle that action.

Comment: It seems like `Execute` implementations would have to have a `switch`/`case` handling each `WeaponCommand` they implement. I don't think that feels good either.

Comment: @NetMage The `Execute` method exists in the context of a single action for a single weapon. That eliminates the `switch`. That was the reason why I suggested it. `SwordSwingStrategy` defines the behavior of a single weapon for a single command. It leaves the door open for re-using a single behavior if you have multiple weapons that both support a "swing" command.

Comment: An example - (I'm not a violent person so I can't even believe I'm describing this) would be two different guns that both fire and reload differently. But perhaps they both behave the same if you're out of ammo and you just want to hit someone with them. They might both use the same `GunUsedAsAClubStrategy`.

Comment: I can see the `SwordSwingStrategy` needed a lot of access to the internals of the `Sword` object? Also, it seems like the strategy doesn't know which weapon is being used? The coupling seems like it needs to be tighter. Also, in your example, would you create two different Reload strategies for the differing guns because that seems extra problematic to me.

Comment: It's just a draft - a very rough one -  all I can write without knowing more details. The weapon invokes the strategy, so the weapon could provide more information to the strategy. Beyond whatever is provided, correct, the strategy wouldn't know about the weapon. You could likely share a reload strategy between guns, whether the same class or derived classes. This is definitely not a fully-baked design. But I'd try to figure out anything other than defining various interfaces and then inspecting an object to see what it implements or requiring classes to have unused, empty methods.